# My TSA pre check was not on my return flight. Is it specific to each flight?

Tags: tsa, tsa-precheck

Do you get the TSA pre check mark for each flight no matter what?  Or is this flight specific?

Comment: Which airlines?

Comment: Are you signed up for TSA Pre-Check? And had you told your airline about your Registered Traveller number?

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed specific to each individual flight, though it will usually be on each boarding pass for a particular part of your trip (i.e. all of your outbound boarding passes or all of your return boarding passes.) You won't know for sure whether you'll get it for a particular part of your trip until you check-in and see your boarding pass. Granted, in most cases, you'll only need to clear security once per direction anyway, but sometimes changing terminals can require clearing security again on a layover (e.g. at LAX or SFO.)

[According to TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/tsa-precheck), there is no guarantee that you will have it on any given flight, even if you have a KTN from TSA or CBP. I have seen many instances personally in which I or someone I was traveling with had it for just the outbound flights and not the return or the other way around.

> TSA incorporates unpredictable security measures throughout the airport and no passenger is guaranteed expedited screening.

Comment: Some airports don't have Pre-Check, so obviously a round-trip to one of them will have Pre-Check only one way.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus True, but I've seen many instances where all airports involved had pre-check lines and, yet, it still printed one way, but not the other. Even between the same pair of airports on different trips, I've had some trips where it only came up on the outbound and some where it only came up on the inbounds. Granted, that was before I actually had a KTN. I still see that, though, for my other family members who don't have KTNs. For example, I recently took a trip with my parents and I had it both ways, while they only had it one way.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Also, I've seen pre-check marked on a boarding pass for a flight departing an airport that definitely didn't have pre-check (the airport in question was in Asia.) It just seems to print on all of the boarding passes for a particular portion of the trip.

Comment: @reirab As the answer states, there is a deliberate element of randomness in it. Sometimes I get pre check despite not being a US citizen and not signed up for the scheme at all.

Comment: @Calchas Right, that was my point.

Comment: Note that being granted TSA Pre-Check approval for a specific flight is independent of the departure airport having Pre-Check.  As an example, I frequently have TSA Pre-Check printed on boarding passes that depart from Tokyo, Hong Kong, and other overseas airports that do not have TSA, much less TSA Pre-Check.